# How to make Eclipse get help from online?

Tags: java, eclipse

On Visual Studio, when I hover over a method or a reserved word and press F1, Visual Studio take me to an online help on that method or reserved word. Yet on Eclipse, when I hover over a reserved word or a method, Eclipse shows me a simple help. How can I make Eclipse show me a more complete help online? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can get the help for something with <kbd>F2</kbd> (cursor position in the text matters, not where your mouse is).

Most of the time, this is the JavaDoc which is often unsatisfactory - JavaDoc is usually just a reference which helps when you already know how to use something and just need to look up a detail.

<kbd>F3</kbd> gets you to the source code of whatever is under the cursor right now - if you have the sources somewhere where Eclipse can find it.

Apart from that, you need to have a web browser open unless you're looking for something Eclipse specific. Eclipse code is documented in the Eclipse online help that you can find in the "Help" menu. I get the best results with the item "Help Contents".

Answer (score 0):

If you have jar files without javadoc included, here are instructions I use:

Open Eclipse
Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
Double click on the   jre7 icon
click Add External JARs
navigate to where your jdk-7u40-apidocs.zip is located
finish
close
restart Eclipse
Open a Java class
Select a java term in the class
Click 
You should now see the javadoc for that item appear

For jar files included in your project (not part of jre):

Right click on the jar file of interest, select properties, select ‘Javadoc Location’, browse to where your javadoc file is located (search Google to locate and download it).